# Can I add dependencies into .rpm which is already built?

Tags: package, fedora, rpm

I have .rpm package which is converted from .deb in Ubuntu with alien.

In fedora it needs another dependencies, but I can't find the way to add dependencies.

and I guess I can't edit .spec file of it becuase what I have is only .rpm file.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make another a dummy package <your-package>-with-<dependency>.

In it's spec file,  besides the required tags, also include Requires tags for your package and the dependencies.

This way, when you installed the dummy package, it would force both your package and the dependencies to be installed.